# Is this $LL(1)$ grammar valid?

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers

Is the following a valid $LL(1)$ grammar:

> $ \begin{align} S &\rightarrow L \$ \\ L &\rightarrow M L_2 \\ L_2
>  &\rightarrow \underline{::} L \\ L_2 &\rightarrow \epsilon \\ M
>  &\rightarrow \underline{id} R \\ R &\rightarrow \underline{(} R_2 \\
>  R_2 &\rightarrow M \underline{)} \\ R_2 &\rightarrow \underline{)}
>  \end{align} $

I am not sure because of $R_2$ since there are two rules I could apply to reach $\$$ (*bottom of stack*) or do I understand something wrong here?

So in the parsing table for $R_2$ under $\$$ I have the options $R_2 \rightarrow M \underline{)}$ and $R_2 \rightarrow \underline{)}$

Could somebody clarify?

Comment: There are (computable) characterisations of LL(1) grammars. Have you checked those? See also [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/6768/98).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have misunderstood what the parsing table does. The parsing table tells for each pair $(A,a)$, where $A$ is a non-terminal symbol and $a$ is a terminal symbol, which grammar rule you have to use so that the next non-terminal symbol produced to the string from the left will be $a$. For example, the symbol $R_2$ produces either the symbol $id$ by the derivation
$$R_2 \rightarrow M) \rightarrow idR)$$ 
or the symbol $)$ by
$$R_2 \rightarrow )$$
Thus in the parsing table, $(R_2, id)$ points to rule "$R_2 \rightarrow M)$", and $(R_2,\textrm{'})\textrm{'})$ points to rule "$R_2 \rightarrow )$". The case $(R_2, \$)$ is a parsing error, since the dollar sign cannot be reached from $R_2$ without first producing either $id$ or $)$. If fact, all other terminal symbols except for $id$ and $)$ are parsing errors.

A grammar is a valid $LL(1)$ grammar if for every pair $(A,a)$ there is only one choice for which grammar rule to use. In our grammar the possibly problematic rules are the ones for $L_2$ and $R_2$, because they have two choices. The rest of the non-terminals are clearly unambiguous, as there is only one choice.

I gave the unambiguous parsing table rules $R_2$ above.
For $L_2$, the only symbols which do not produce a parsing error are $\epsilon$ and $::$. For $\epsilon$ we use the rule $L_2 \rightarrow \epsilon$, and for $::$ we use the rule $L_2 \rightarrow :: L$. Therefore the parsing rules for $L_2$ is also unambiguous, and in conclusion the grammar is a valid $LL(1)$ grammar.

Comment: Hi! The thing is that $FOLLOW(R_2) = \{\underline{::}, \epsilon, \$\}$ if I'm not mistaken e.g. for an input $\underline{id}\underline{(}\underline{)}$ the end of stack $\$$ follows after $R_2$. But this holds for *both* rules of $R_2$. I think this is where my confusion begins.